# wordpress plugin MVC page structure

Tags: model-view-controller, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin that takes the whole page and is about planing a trip.

The plugin spread out and contains several modules and more than 10 "views" (Booking, Billing, Register, My Profile, My Bookings, My comments, etc.).

I have a strong OOP and MVC background but this plugin was originally created on a single template with everything loaded with ajax and not in a organized way :)

- What is good practice for organizing big plugins (semi small sites) in wordpress?
- Is there a way to create direct links for the modules view files? something like:
  domain.com/blog/wp/plugins/my_plugin/profile.php

**Bounty**:
I'm looking for guidelines here from people with experience.

Comment: How exactly are wordpress (which implements "big ball of mud" architectural pattern) plugins related to MVC application architecture?

Comment: I don't like working in a "big ball of mud" architecture, but my task is to build a large wordpress plugin, so I'm looking for guidelines / experienced appenion on how to make it less muddy and more structured.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, it's not easy to do, and it's harder to stick to as development progresses.

I'll try to answer your bullet points first, then try to talk about some architecture stuff I try to adhere to.

- I organize them as close to normal as possible. So I usually end up with folders for Models, Controllers, Views. Try to write your application as much as possible in the same manner you would for anything else.
- Use [`plugin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

If you're working on a project that won't be distributed (i.e. not a publicly released plugin), you've got some advantages because you can load in outside packages from Composer without worrying about conflicts from other places. So wherever possible, I'd advise offloading stuff to Composer.

I'm not a fan of how PHP implemented Namespaces, but I'm a huge fan of using them in conjunction with autoloading. You'll definitely make things easier on yourself if you use some form of [Autoloading](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), even if it's not used with Namespaces.

Since WordPress works off of functional hooks, unless you (over?)engineer a lot of stuff, you're always going to end up with a bunch of hooks all over the place. Generally, my advice there is to try and keep those together in a file, and to never put hooks inside classes, especially constructors. Keep stuff in logical groups.

The trick really is to minimize the number of points where you're actually interacting with WordPress, and everywhere else to essentially write your code as you normally would, with decent design patterns and the like. You'll have to have certain points of contact (like the hooks and such) where you'll probably find yourself making some concessions to WordPress, but even there you can mitigate it by loading object methods as hook callbacks, and using those as jumping-off points to a "normal" application.

I've been interested in this problem for a while. I've got a couple ongoing projects in this area. One thing I threw together was for interfacing with GravityForms, and it's on [github](https://github.com/jdpedrie/gravityforms-hook-controller/tree/89bab9cc1678f1af38b19320ba17b50b7636d906). It's really not complicated, but it might help explain some of how I've got about solving the problem.

I'm running out of specifics to add, but please feel free to drop me a line if you like. As I said, I'm really interested in solving this problem, and I think that if WordPress lasts and continues to be as popular as it is today, we'll have better solutions coming around.

I hope this is helpful!

**EDIT:** A more concrete example

I'll point some stuff out in the code I shared originally. It's sort of specialized, but you can use the principles for any hook-based functionality. As you can see [here](https://github.com/jdpedrie/gravityforms-hook-controller/blob/89bab9cc1678f1af38b19320ba17b50b7636d906/gravityforms.phpp#L23-L24), I'm invoking a method of class `GravityFormsHooks\Loader` to handle hooking into objects. In [`GravityFormsHooks\Loader`](https://github.com/jdpedrie/gravityforms-hook-controller/blob/89bab9cc1678f1af38b19320ba17b50b7636d906/GravityFormsHooks/Loader.php#L33-L36), I'm calling [another static method on that class](https://github.com/jdpedrie/gravityforms-hook-controller/blob/89bab9cc1678f1af38b19320ba17b50b7636d906/GravityFormsHooks/Loader.php#L76-L91) to actually execute the hook. This example will take either an action or filter, but it's tailored to Gravityforms specifically, so YMMV.

Essentially what this `GravityFormsHooks\Loader::hook()` method does is instantiate the class we're hooking into, and generate the hook as normal.

The class I'm calling from the main plugin file is [`GravityFormsHooks\Forms\Form`](https://github.com/jdpedrie/gravityforms-hook-controller/blob/89bab9cc1678f1af38b19320ba17b50b7636d906/GravityFormsHooks/Forms/Form.php). Note that any method you hook onto MUST be declared as `public`. If we're going to shoehorn ourselves into an MVC paradigm, this method here would be your controller. From there, you can jump off to injecting models, a template engine, all manner of cool stuff.

As I mentioned in my original post, I try to keep my points of contact with WordPress to an absolute minimum. I don't mean that you should write APIs doing stuff WordPress already has APIs for, just that your hooks should be centralized and minimized. It really is a useful separation of concerns, and as your application grows it'll help you to manage the complexity a lot more easily.

The examples I provided should work pretty well as a Hook Controller, with minimum modifications to remove some of the more specialized GravityForms stuff.

Let me know if you've got any other questions.

Comment: I like the structure of your plugin, but it doesn't have a composer.json. How are you including twig?

Comment: It's supposed to have a composer.json. I pushed it to github a while ago to show it to someone and never added the rest of the stuff it needs to work. :-/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the major milestone is to create a good base-template(front controller?) in which as you said to separate wordpress hooks and relation from your OOP code. Do you have any example for this ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more detailed walkthrough using the plugin I shared before.